# Access granted to groups and roles in Hue has no effect

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, hue, cloudera-manager

When I give Grant to groups and roles in hue, nothing happens to the groups and no access is applied!

```
CREATE ROLE admin_role
GRANT ALL ON SERVER server1 TO ROLE admin_role
GRANT ROLE admin_role TO GROUP sentry_admin;
```

Comment: You do have Sentry-HDFS sync properly enabled, right? https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/sg_hdfs_sentry_sync.html